# question on compensated poisson random measure

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, levy-processes

In David Applebaum's book *Levy Processes and Stochastic Calculus*, it defines stochastic integral with respect to **martingale-valued** measure(roughly speaking, a random measure on $\mathbb{R}^+\times E$ that makes $M([0,t],A)$ is a martingale for each A in $\mathbb{B}(E)$. Here, $E$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}^d$).

The most important martingale-valued measure is the compensated poisson random measure. However, the compensated measure can be well defined only when $0\notin\bar{E}$. Otherwise it causes $\infty-\infty$ which is meaningless. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809558/when-is-the-compensated-poisson-random-measure-a-martingale-extensions-to-set) for more details.

And right now I am quite confused that how can we define stochastic integral with respect to compensated poisson random measure. Should we use approximation method in some sense?